# Cual es la diferencia en utilizar un objeto a una variableObjeto

Tags: python, lista, poo, estructuras-de-datos, nodos

Me encontre con una **duda de POO** al hacer una **Lista simplemente enlazada** la cual funciona perfectamente hasta que en ves de utilizar un objeto almacenado previamente en una variable auxiliar utilizo el objeto directamente:

```
class  Nodo()
    def __init__ (self, dato):
        self.dato = dato
        self.siguienteNodo = None   


class ListaSiempleEnlazada ():      
    def __init__(self):
        self.primerNodo = None  
        self.ultimoNodo = None 

    def agregar_ultimoNodo(self, dato):
        aux = Nodo(dato)            

        if self.primerNodo == None:
            self.primerNodo = self.ultimoNodo = newNodo
        else:                   
            self.ultimoNodo.siguienteNodo = aux
            self.ultimoNodo = aux

    def eliminar_ultimoNodo(self):
        nodo = self.primerNodo
        while nodo.siguienteNodo != self.ultimoNodo:
            nodo = nodo.siguienteNodo

        nodo.siguienteNodo = None
        self.ultimoNodo = nodo      

    def recorrer(self):
        nodo = self.primerNodo 
        while nodo != None:
            print(nodo.dato)
            nodo = nodo.siguienteNodo

array = ListaSiempleEnlazada()
array.agregar_ultimoNodo(12) 
array.agregar_ultimoNodo(2)

array.eliminar_ultimoNodo()
```

Porq en el metodo de `agregar_ultimoNodo` no puedo utilizar directamente `Nodo(dato)` y lo tengo que almacenar en una variable auxiliar para que funcione ??

En caso contrario:

```
def agregar_ultimoNodo(self, dato):
    #....           
        self.ultimoNodo.siguienteNodo = Nodo(dato)
        self.ultimoNodo = Nodo(dato)
```

daria error al eliminar el ultimo nodo: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'siguienteNodo'`:

Comment: No se me ocurre como dar una respuesta, pero considera que `aux = obj() a=aux b=aux` NO hacen lo mismo que `a = obj() b = obj()`. Esto se debe a que, en Python, las variables funcionan por referencia. Es decir, la variable es tan solo "un nombre que le das a un objeto". En `aux = obj() a=aux b=aux` estás nombrando la instancia de obj como aux y dandole los "otros nombres" a y b. En cambio en  `a = obj() b = obj()` se crean dos cosas distintas y se le da a la primera el "nombre" a y a la segunda el "nombre" b.

Comment: Antes de copiar y pegar código en comentarios, te aviso que no se ve bien el código en comentarios. Si querés agregar info a la pregunta, te recomiendo editarla.

Answer (score 1):

Si asignas como dices en tu segunda opción:

```
        self.ultimoNodo.siguienteNodo = Nodo(dato)
        self.ultimoNodo = Nodo(dato)
```

lo que ocurre es que `self.ultimoNodo.siguienteNodo` apunta a un objeto diferente de `self.ultimonodo`. Esto puedes comprobarlo comparando `self.ultimoNodo.siguienteNodo is self.ultimoNodo` y verás que da `False`.

En cambio con la asignación:

```
            self.ultimoNodo.siguienteNodo = aux
            self.ultimoNodo = aux
```

ambos apuntan a un mismo objeto (que será el objeto apuntado por `aux`) y puedes verificar que `self.ultimoNodo.siguienteNodo is self.ultimoNodo` ya devuelve `True`.

¿Por qué habría de ser importante si apuntan al mismo o no? Creo que el problema lo tienes a la hora de eliminar el ultimo nodo, pues tienes esto:

```
        while nodo.siguienteNodo != self.ultimoNodo:
            nodo = nodo.siguienteNodo
```

creo que el `while` nunca llega a ser cierto, debido a que el valor que asignaste a `siguienteNodo` cuando añadiste el último no coincide con el que después guardaste en `self.ultimoNodo`. Es decir, ningún nodo de tu lista cumple que su siguiente sea igual a `self.ultimoNodo`.

Por tanto acaba por llegar al último "sin darse cuenta", asigna `nodo = nodo.siguienteNodo` que en el caso del último deja `nodo = None` y luego rompe al intentar acceder a `nodo.siguienteNodo` porque `None` no es un objeto que tenga ese campo.

**Nota**

Al margen de lo anterior, aún cuando lo haces bien a través de `aux` creo que sería más correcto en `eliminar_ultimoNodo()` que el bucle fuese:

```
        while nodo.siguienteNodo is not self.ultimoNodo:
            nodo = nodo.siguienteNodo
```

Es decir, usar `is not` en vez de `!=` ya que `is` compara si las referencias apuntan o no al mismo objeto (mientras que `==` y `!=` comparan los contenidos de los objetos en sí, y no las referencias).